# Android Studio: Gradle project sync failed. Please fix your project and try again

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, compilation, dependencies

Running my project gives me the following issue:

> Gradle project sync failed. Please fix your project and try again

in fact that is not the console output but a window when I try to run the android project:

[image]

I do not know what could be wrong..

my project gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:+'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-alpha3'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
        }
        maven {
            url "http://dl.bintray.com/glomadrian/maven"
        }
        maven {
            url "https://s3.amazonaws.com/repo.commonsware.com"
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots" }
    }
}
```

my app gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 23
        buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.example.jublikon"
            minSdkVersion 21
            targetSdkVersion 23
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            multiDexEnabled true
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
        sourceSets {
            main { res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res', 'src/main/res/drawable/ic_action_search.png'] }
        }
        productFlavors {
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

        //Google Libraries
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.+'
        compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.+'
        compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.+'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'

        //Third party libraries
        compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.6'
        compile 'jp.wasabeef:recyclerview-animators:1.2.0@aar'
        compile('com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.8.2.0@aar') {transitive = true }
        compile 'com.pixplicity.easyprefs:library:1.7'
        compile 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.8.4'
        compile 'com.github.navasmdc:MaterialDesign:1.5@aar'
        compile 'com.github.rey5137:material:1.2.1.6-SNAPSHOT'
        compile 'com.github.ViksaaSkool:AwesomeSplash:v1.0.0'
        compile 'com.github.paolorotolo:appintro:3.3.0'
        compile ('com.github.ganfra:material-spinner:1.1.1'){
            exclude group: 'com.nineoldandroids', module: 'library'
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v7'
        }
        compile 'com.github.glomadrian:MaterialAnimatedSwitch:1.1@aar'
        compile 'com.commonsware.cwac:provider:0.3.+'
        compile 'com.rockerhieu.emojicon:library:1.3.2'
    }

    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Error log:

```
18:13:42 Gradle build finished in 1m 17s 236ms
18:13:42 Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]
18:13:43 EmptyThrowable: The APK file /Users/jublikon/Development/sampleApp/app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk does not exist on disk.
```

after a clean I got that window:

[image]

how can I fix that issue?

Comment: on the right of `android studio` click `Gradle`, then `:app`, then `build`, then `assembleDebug` - tell me if doesn't work

Comment: works fine. thank you ;)